# Unable to animate tabbed activity on finishing the activity

Tags: android, animation

Following is the code of tabbed activity class

```
public class TabbedActivity extends TabActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    setContentView(R.layout.inbox_tab_layout);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    // Tab for Songs
    TabHost.TabSpec loc = tabHost.newTabSpec("Confirm Location");
    loc.setIndicator("Confirm Location");
    Intent location = new Intent(this, LocationTab.class);
    loc.setContent(location);

    // Tab for Videos
    TabHost.TabSpec edit = tabHost.newTabSpec("Medinfi");
    edit.setIndicator("Add Details");
    Intent videosIntent = new Intent(this, EditTab.class);
    edit.setContent(videosIntent);

    tabHost.addTab(loc); // Adding songs tab
    tabHost.addTab(edit); // Adding videos tab
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Data.activityResumed();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Data.activityPaused();
}
```

}

I'm trying to animate the activity by using `overridependingintent` by overriding onBackPressed using code mentioned below.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
}
```

But the code doesn't work. Animation doesn't execute, rather the default animation takes place.

Answer (score 0):

If you took it from an example ,notice ,this code is very OLD

1. TabActivity is depcrecated since API 13 ,use ActionBar.addTab or FragmentActivity with TabHost (since you already have the code for TabHost)
2. You can use android:windowEnterTransition / android:windowExitTransition in the XML of the activities.
3. If you're aiming to JELLY_BEANS and up use ActivityOptions instead

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i resolved this by overriding finish() method instead